# How does scikit's cross validation work?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I have the following snippet:

```
print '\nfitting'
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(
    n_estimators=10,
    max_features='auto',
    criterion='mse',
    max_depth=None,
)
rfr.fit(X_train, y_train)


# scores
scores = cross_val_score(
    estimator=rfr,
    X=X_test,
    y=y_test,
    verbose=1,
    cv=10,
    n_jobs=4,
)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

1) Does running the cross_val_score do more training on the regressor?

2) Do I need to pass in a trained regressor or just a new one, e.g. `estimator=RandomForestRegressor()`. How then do I test the accuracy of a regressor, i.e. must I use another function in scikit?

3) My accuracy is about 2%. Is that the MSE score, where lower is better or is it the actual accuracy. If it is the actual accuracy, can you explain it, because it doesn't make sense how a regressor will accurately predict on a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It re-trains the estimator, *k* times in fact.
2. Untrained (or trained, but then the model is deleted and you're just wasting time).
3. It's the [R² score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), so that's not actually 2% but .02; R² is capped at 1 but can be negative. Accuracy is not well-defined for regression. (You can define it as for classification, but that makes no sense.)